# Typescript 2.8+: how to capture and map action creators to action handlers?

Tags: typescript, redux

I have the following action creators:

```
/** simply captures the string literal type */
function actionType<T extends string, U>(type: T, u: U) {
  return Object.assign({}, { type }, u);
}

// ------------------------------------
// Action Creators
// ------------------------------------
const ACTION_CREATORS = {
  toggleFilter: (params: { filterValueKey: string; filterKey: string; filterValue: string }) => {
    const { filterKey, filterValue, filterValueKey } = params;
    return actionType('FILTERS_TOGGLE', {
      payload: {
        filterValueKey,
        filterKey,
        filterValue
      }
    });
  },
  deleteFilter: (params: { filterValueKey: string }) => {
    const { filterValueKey } = params;
    return actionType('FILTERS_DELETE', {
      payload: {
        filterValueKey
      }
    });
  },
  searchFilterValues: (params: { activeFilterKey: string; query: string }) => {
    const { query, activeFilterKey } = params;
    return actionType('FILTERS_QUERY_VALUES', {
      payload: {
        query,
        activeFilterKey
      }
    });
  }
};
```

and what I'd like to write is a

```
type ActionHandlers<T extends {
  [actionCreator: string]: (...args: any[]) => { type: string }
}> = { /* ... */ };
```

that will add the correct typings for an "action handlers" object like the one below:

```
const ACTION_HANDLERS: ActionHandlers<typeof ACTION_CREATORS > = {
  FILTERS_TOGGLE: (state, action) => {
    action.payload.filterValueKey // this key is typed
    const newState = { ...state };
    return newState;
  },
  FILTERS_DELETE: () => {} /* ... */,
  FILTERS_QUERY_VALUES: (state, action) => {
    action.payload.query // this is also typed and typed differently
    const newState = { ...state };
    return newState;
  }
}
```

---

So far I am able to capture the names of the action types and grabs the return types of the action creators but I'm stuck at this point:

```
type Action<T extends { type: string }> = T;

type ActionCreator<T extends string> = (...params: any[]) => { type: T };
type MapToNames<T extends { [key: string]: ActionCreator<any> }> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends ActionCreator<infer U> ? U : never
};
type ActionNames<T extends { [key: string]: ActionCreator<any> }> = MapToNames<
  T
>[keyof MapToNames<T>];

type RemoveFunctions<T extends { [key: string]: (...args: any[]) => { type: string } }> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends (...params: any[]) => Action<infer U> ? U : never
};

type Names = ActionNames<typeof ACTION_CREATORS>;
// type Names = "FILTERS_TOGGLE" | "FILTERS_DELETE" | "FILTERS_QUERY_VALUES"
type NoFunctions = RemoveFunctions<typeof ACTION_CREATORS>;
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What about the type of the state ? what should that be ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir the type of state can just be a generic parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be one possible solution:

```
type GetActionCreatorTypes<T extends { [key: string]: (...args: any[]) => { type: string } }> = {
    // Get the return type of the action creator
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends (...params: any[]) => Action<infer U> ? U : never
}[keyof T]; // Make a union of all action types 


type ActionHandlers<T extends {
    [actionCreator: string]: (...args: any[]) => { type: string }
}> = {
        // Take all properties named type (will be a union of "FILTERS_TOGGLE" | "FILTERS_DELETE" | "FILTERS_QUERY_VALUES" in our case)
        [P in GetActionCreatorTypes<T>['type']]: (
            state: any, 
            // Type the action as beeing the only type in the union with the type property named P
            action: Extract<GetActionCreatorTypes<T>, { type: P }>
        ) => any 
    };


const ACTION_HANDLERS: ActionHandlers<typeof ACTION_CREATORS> = {
    FILTERS_TOGGLE: (state, action) => {
        action.payload.filterValueKey // ok 
        const newState = { ...state };
        return newState;
    },
    FILTERS_DELETE: () => { } /* ... */,
    FILTERS_QUERY_VALUES: (state, action) => {
        action.payload.query // this is also ok
        const newState = { ...state };
        return newState;
    }
}
```

Playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Action%3CT%20extends%20%7B%20type%3A%20string%20%7D%3E%20%3D%20T%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ActionCreator%3CT%20extends%20string%3E%20%3D%20(...params%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20type%3A%20T%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20GetActionCreatorTypes%3CT%20extends%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20type%3A%20string%20%7D%20%7D%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Get%20the%20return%20type%20of%20the%20action%20creator%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20T%5BP%5D%20extends%20(...params%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20Action%3Cinfer%20U%3E%20%3F%20U%20%3A%20never%0D%0A%7D%5Bkeyof%20T%5D%3B%20%2F%2F%20Make%20a%20union%20of%20all%20action%20types%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ActionHandlers%3CT%20extends%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BactionCreator%3A%20string%5D%3A%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20type%3A%20string%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Take%20all%20properties%20named%20type%20(will%20be%20a%20union%20of%20%22FILTERS_TOGGLE%22%20%7C%20%22FILTERS_DELETE%22%20%7C%20%22FILTERS_QUERY_VALUES%22%20in%20our%20case)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5BP%20in%20GetActionCreatorTypes%3CT%3E%5B'type'%5D%5D%3A%20(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20state%3A%20any%2C%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Type%20the%20action%20as%20beeing%20the%20only%20type%20in%20the%20union%20with%20the%20type%20property%20named%20P%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20action%3A%20Extract%3CGetActionCreatorTypes%3CT%3E%2C%20%7B%20type%3A%20P%20%7D%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%20%3D%3E%20any%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20ACTION_HANDLERS%3A%20ActionHandlers%3Ctypeof%20ACTION_CREATORS%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTERS_TOGGLE%3A%20(state%2C%20action)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20action.payload.filterValueKey%20%2F%2F%20ok%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20newState%20%3D%20%7B%20...state%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20newState%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTERS_DELETE%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D%20%2F*%20...%20*%2F%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTERS_QUERY_VALUES%3A%20(state%2C%20action)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20action.payload.query%20%2F%2F%20this%20is%20also%20ok%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20newState%20%3D%20%7B%20...state%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20newState%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F**%20simply%20captures%20the%20string%20literal%20type%20*%2F%0D%0Afunction%20actionType%3CT%20extends%20string%2C%20U%3E(type%3A%20T%2C%20u%3A%20U)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20%7B%20type%20%7D%2C%20u)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20------------------------------------%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Action%20Creators%0D%0A%2F%2F%20------------------------------------%0D%0Aconst%20ACTION_CREATORS%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20toggleFilter%3A%20(params%3A%20%7B%20filterValueKey%3A%20string%3B%20filterKey%3A%20string%3B%20filterValue%3A%20string%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20%7B%20filterKey%2C%20filterValue%2C%20filterValueKey%20%7D%20%3D%20params%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20actionType('FILTERS_TOGGLE'%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20payload%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20filterValueKey%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20filterKey%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20filterValue%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20deleteFilter%3A%20(params%3A%20%7B%20filterValueKey%3A%20string%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20%7B%20filterValueKey%20%7D%20%3D%20params%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20actionType('FILTERS_DELETE'%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20payload%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20filterValueKey%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%)

Comment: this is crazy good (and maybe blog post worthy?). thanks a bunch!